# Can you build 10.7 applications with xcode 3?

Tags: xcode, macos

Can you build Mac SDK 10.7 applications without having Mac SDK 10.7? Such as with an old Xcode?

Or do you need a new one? And what's the earliest 10.7 SDK was included in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build applications that run on 10.7, but in order to use 10.7 specific API calls you need to build with Xcode on 10.7 or later.

The earliest Xcode that included the 10.7 SDK was Xcode 4.2 for Lion. Note that the Snow Leopard version of Xcode 4.2 does not include the 10.7 SDK.

You can Drag and Drop older SDKs into newer versions of Xcode and usually get them to work, you can't go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.  In order to build apps for 10.7 you need the 10.7 library, which is only available in Xcode 4